# how to link to page in Next.js with locale when project is in subdirectory?

Tags: next.js, next-router, next-link

I have a problem with routing in next.js.
Project on the server is in subdirectory: exmaple.com/app.

Routing i want to achieve: `example.com/app/<locale>/<pageName>`
(add prefix before url). When I'm trying to add it in href `Link` generates url this way: `example.com/<locale>/app/<pageName>`

Is there a way to add locale after prefix, not the other way around?
When I use basePath it servers my app in example.com/app/app because project is in subdirectory /app

```
//next.config.js
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

module.exports = {
    i18n,
    basePath: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? '/app' : '',
    assetPrefix: '/app/',
};
```

Custom link component used to wrap links:

```
//link.tsx
import React from 'react';
import NextLink, { LinkProps } from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export interface ILinkProps extends LinkProps {
    children: React.ReactChild;
    asLink?: boolean;
}

Link.defaultProps = {
    asLink: false,
};

export default function Link(props: ILinkProps): React.ReactElement {
    const { children, asLink, href, locale, ...rest } = props;

    const router = useRouter();

    const currentLocale = router.locale;

    return (
        <>
            {asLink ? (
                <NextLink
                    {...rest}
                    href={href}
                    locale={locale || currentLocale}
                    as={href}
                    passHref
                >
                    {children}
                </NextLink>
            ) : (
                children
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Adding the locale after the `basePath` should be the default behaviour. Can you show how you're setting up the `Link` in your code?

Comment: I did mistake in description: on the server because project is in subcategory I'm not using basepath. Basepath is used only on localhost. I will update description